# can I use an aluminium seatpost to install a tagalong on a carbon fiber frame?

Tags: carbon, seatpost

I've been told not to put a tagalong on my carbon bike because the carbon seat post could crack because they aren't designed to withstand the lateral tension of having the tagalong mounted there.

I'm curious if it'd be OK if I were to just mount an aluminium seat post there instead, and then mount the tagalong to the aluminium seatpost.   Will that risk the frame getting cracked knowing that the tagalong will create some extra lateral tension, or is the mouth of the seatpost hole generally strong enough to withstand a little extra weight?

This would most likely be a temporary installation, so I'm not concerned about the metal/carbon corrosion issue... only about potentially cracking my seatpost hole.

Comment: Contact you frame manufacturer to determine if this type of use is covered by the warranty.

Comment: I assume the seatpost will crack before the frame does, so it might be better to use a sacrificial carbon seatpost

Comment: @Nic the problem is that most people value the child on the tagalong much more than they value the bike. So anything where the failure mode is "kid bites the bitumen" is out.

Comment: Consider buying a cheap used steel MTB for family trips instead of your carbon racer.

Comment: I always got advised to not mix carbon with aluminium. Apparently they can melt together and it will be impossible to remove the post.

Comment: @Criggie but how will I measure my watts while hammering it out on the trails when my power2max is installed on my racer?  I can't afford 2 power meters, that's just wasting money that could go toward a new wheel set!

Comment: @jason Remember riding with the kids is about doing something together.  You don't need a power meter on your tractor-bike.   If you haven't bought the tagalong yet, consider one that fastens to a rear axle like a trailer.  If you already own it, consider a plastic shim between seatpost and hitch - something ablative so it takes the damage not the bike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the realm of things where nobody can tell you it's absolutely going to be fine, but it will probably be fine. There are some wimpy carbon frames in the world. Also it depends on how much you weigh, because as far as the frame is concerned, the forces generated by the trail-a-bike are going to be added to those generated from your seated weight. If this is a road bike and you're at around the weight limit already, it's probably not a good idea.